# How to set background color of copy and paste tool bar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Look the bellow image.
[image]

If I mark any text then the **top white toolbar** come here. But I want to set **the top white toolbar** on my **custom toolbar** (*red toolbar*).

How I can do that?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **`actionModeBackground`** in your theme

```
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/yourcolor</item>
```

For example,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground" >@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/yourcolor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It change color properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your theme like this

`<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>`

2. In your activity`s onCreate method add this`setSupportActionBar(myToolbar)`

Comment: I used custom toolbar. I write `setSupportActionBar(myCustomToolbar)` into **onCreate()** method. But it don't show any action!

Comment: Have you changed your app or activity theme?

Comment: Yes I change my activity theme.